# How to Aceess this Values. use any loop?

Tags: magento-1.9, fedex

I have got the api response now i want to get only one value from the response.

I want to this value from response `[progressdetails] = > array()`

[image]

Comment: I am not sure it is possible without a loop. You have function getAllTrackings but if you are sure you want the first, you'll need to array_shift on both trackings and progressdetails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($response as $tracking_status){

   $data = $tracking_status-> getAllData();
   print_r($data);

}
```

you can also used:

`$response = Mage::getModel('usa/shipping_carrier_fedex')->getTracking(track_number);
$trackData = $response->getAllTrackings();
$progressData = $trackData[0]->getData('progressdetail');
$deliveredStatus = $progressData[0]['activity'];`

Comment: welcome :) Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

You use the following code assuming `$response` contains your response:

```
foreach ($response->getTrackings() as $tracking)
{
    $progressDetails = $tracking->getProgressdetail();
}
```

If you want to get the first progress details of the first tracking you can do:

```
$trackings = $response->getTrackings();
if ($trackings)
{
    $firstTracking = $trackings[0];
    $progressDetails = $firstTracking->getProgressdetail();
}
```

Comment: @AshvinMonpara see my edit

Comment: i try this anwer but not give any data

Answer (score 0):

Using below code

I assume $response is model here and trackings have only one item.

```
$response->getCollection()->getFirstItem()->getData();
```

Hope this will helpful.

Comment: I don't think this code will work if several trackings are being returned.

Comment: thanks i have create cron.php  But Not Give any Data

Comment: That is correct but in question have only one trackings so i suggest this one.

Comment: @PrashantValanda how do you know there's only one tracking ? As we can see the end of the response

Comment: I have  this code in cron.php but not give any data

Comment: it's give Blank page..

Comment: updated answer try with it

Comment: i wii try this anwer but not give any data